# update indexedDB data

Tags: indexeddb

I am trying to update my indexed DB data . what i have done is this..

```
    function update_doc() {
    var id = document.getElementById("txt_id").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("txt_name").value;
    console.log("About to update " + id + "/" + name);
    var transaction = db.transaction(["stud_store"], "readwrite");
    var store = transaction.objectStore("stud_store");
    var stud = {
        id: id,
        name: name,
        created: new Date()
    }
    var putresult = store.put(stud);
    putresult.onsuccess = function (e) {
        alert("Successfully Done...!");
        console.log("Woot! Did it");
    };
    putresult.onerror = function (e) {
        alert("Something is wrong (Error name: " + e.target.error.name + "  Error message: " + e.target.error.message + ").");
        console.log("Error", e.target.error.id);
        console.dir(e.target);
    }
}
```

(Where id is unique) I am getting the following error...

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you created your objectstores?

Answer (score -1):

Did you forget to open the database?

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open("MyDatabase", 3);
```

docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB

Some more code to show how you created and opened your database might help.

Comment: I think he did open the database, because of the error he showed.